# How to upload .pdf, .docx, .xls in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Ionic File Transfer option showing image upload but there is no option showing file type of doc, pdf, csv.

```
let options: FileUploadOptions = {
     fileKey: 'file',
     fileName: 'name.jpg',
     headers: {}
     .....
  }
```

Explain to me the option.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass mimeType and you can send any file

Example - i send text file to the server fileTransfer.upload(file, url, options) where file is native path and url your server address and options given below

```
   let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'performance',
      fileName: 'Result'+this.id+'.txt',
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "text/plain",
      headers : {'authtoken': this.token},
      params:{'userid':this.id }

 console.info(options.params,options.fileName)
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
       fileTransfer.upload(file, url, options)
       .then((data) => {
```